# using solve function to solve an equation in R

Tags: r, matrix, equation

I'm JeongHyun.

I think this is related to basic R logic, but anyway, I'm confused how 'mat' and 'b' is solved because 'mat' is 3 by 3 matrix and 'b' is 1 by 3 matrix. 
As far as I know, ncol of former matrix and nrow of latter matrix should be same but in this case they are not same.

```
x=c(1,3,5,2,5,1,2,3,8)
x
#[1] 1 3 5 2 5 1 2 3 8

mat=matrix(x,nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    5    1
[3,]    2    3    8

b=c(10,8,3)
b
#[1] 10  8  3

solve(mat,b)
[1] -9.28  5.16  0.76
```

Please let me know how it works.

Thank you.

Comment: `b` is not a matrix. It is a vector. R prints it on a line (for convenience), but you can consider it a column in this context.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. but if so, if there is a vector, how can I consider it as a column or row? Is it up to context?

Comment: Have you read `help("solve")`? If you need to distinguish between a 1 x n matrix and an n x 1 matrix, your object must be a matrix.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now it makes sense to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

R will consider a vector as column matrix in such situations. 
Proof:

```
x=c(1,3,5,2,5,1,2,3,8)
x
#[1] 1 3 5 2 5 1 2 3 8

mat=matrix(x,nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    5    1
[3,]    2    3    8

b=c(10,8,3)
b
#[1] 10  8  3

b<-as.matrix(b)

solve(mat,b)
      [,1]
[1,] -9.28
[2,]  5.16
[3,]  0.76

b1<-t(b)

solve(mat,b1)
#Error in solve.default(mat, b1) : 
  'b1' (1 x 3) must be compatible with 'a' (3 x 3)
```